# Remove "(incl. tax)" from Woocommerce tables and emails

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the "(incl. tax)" fromm Woocommerce cart and checkout tables as well as emails. I still need to keep the "(incl. ...$ tax)" that shows the actual tax amount and is displayed in the totals row. If I simply use

```
.tax_label{
           display:none;
          }
```

it is still displaye in emails and I'd prefer a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

To edit Woocommerce emails, you have to edit the email template files:
https://woocommerce.com/posts/how-to-customize-emails-in-woocommerce/

Not hard to do, just remember to copy your customizations into the current theme, and remember to copy them and test them again if you change themes.

**EDIT:**

To edit the template files for woocommerce, the files are

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php

Copy them to your theme as recommended in the link above.  I don't really remember exactly what line to edit, but a little experimenting won't hurt.  Just play around a bit until you get the results you are after.

Comment: No, I would like to remove them from the shop as well as I mentioned, by PHP,not css.

Comment: My misunderstanding.  See amended info.